# Unity 2019.1 компиляция в apk

Tags: c#, gradle, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

Не компилируется в apk, ошибка CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
Раньше решалось это в настройке Build System - надо было Gradle на Internal поменять, а теперь в новой версии Unity я не нахожу настройку Build System [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.  C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\2019.1.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe
>   -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\2019.1.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar"
>   org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m"
>   "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:\Users\Rinachi\Documents\�������� C#\������ �� ����� Unity � ��������\FPS2\Temp\gradleOut\build.gradle' line: 24

Comment: Мне бы просто найти настройку Build System

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. С Unity3d 2019 [этот тип сборки недоступен](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta/2019.1.0b1) в принципе:

   > Android: Remove internal build system
2. [Подробные логи ошибки в редакторе](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) лежат в `C:\Users\имя_пользователя\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\Editor.log`.
3. Попробуйте переместить проект в директорию без русских символов в пути и пересоберите.

Comment: 3 способ работает, спасибо большое

Comment: @РинатАюпов рад был помочь (: