# Не получается создать сборку в Unity под Android

Tags: unity3d, gradle, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

При попытке создать сборку под Android в Unity выходит ошибка:

> Gradle build failed.See the Console for details.

В самой консоли написано:

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors   at
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
>   (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00234] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:191
>   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean
>   askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions)
>   [0x0007f] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Версия Unity 2018.3.14f1

Путь к SDK: `C:\Users\Евгений\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

Путь к JDK: `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.3.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows`

Comment: у меня иногда выдавало такое.  Мне помогал экспорт в андроид студию

Comment: и там выдает более понятные ошибки которые можно дальше решать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте переместить проект в директорию без русских символов в пути и соберите.

А подробные логи лежат в: `C:\Users\имя_пользователя\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\Editor.log`.

Comment: вот эти подробные логи. Я не могу в них разобраться:(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kCpEmQnZFuIy4ZLAykO_8xlDIkRvWGfY/view

Comment: Вот что выдаёт Unity сейчас: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16Rn3K-yC1ubIgstypncDU1kApd-8-QS5

Comment: @ЕвгенийСкворцов в директории проекта не должно быть русских символов.

Comment: Русских символов сейчас нет. Проблема не устраняется. Вот путь в котором находиться проект:C:\ProjectUnity\BloodyNinja

Comment: @ЕвгенийСкворцов покажите логи после переноса.

Comment: Логи после переноса проекта по пути C:\ProjectUnity\BloodyNinja https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eFIKO3NaP8TWF7JX653gEJYbQEKQ6Oeg

Comment: @ЕвгенийСкворцов у вас имя юзера на русском что ли? D:

Comment: Да :D неужели в этом может быть проблема? Вот где лежит у меня android SDK: C:\Users\Евгений\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

Comment: @ЕвгенийСкворцов может, там сборка плохо работает, если в пути русские символы.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСкворцов вернее, не работает совсем. Вчера у человека [такая же проблема была](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1005915/15479).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Поменял имя пользователя и все стало хорошо:D

Answer (score 0):

Поставь Android SDK (Android Deveopment Kit) И потом в панели сверху Edit>Preferences>External Tools> В строке Android SDK укажи путь к папке с установленным Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

Здраствуйте помогите с ошибкой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ» пожалуйста удалите.